# XCTest fails after adding CloudKit capability

Tags: xcode, code-signing, cloudkit, xctest

After I enabled CloudKit my tests fail to run, apparently because the test bundle cannot be code signed correctly:

```
The bundle “XXXTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2020-01-06 09:11:40.551130+0100 XXX[2581:20975 (dlopen_preflight(/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-gznytogyqukfvnawlueveokdvdrw/Build/Products/Debug/XXX.app/Contents/PlugIns/XXXTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/XXXTests): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-gznytogyqukfvnawlueveokdvdrw/Build/Products/Debug/XXX.app/Contents/PlugIns/XXXTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/XXXTests: code signature invalid for '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-gznytogyqukfvnawlueveokdvdrw/Build/Products/Debug/XXX.app/Contents/PlugIns/XXXTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/XXXTests')
```

I already tried cleaning the build folder, remove the derived data folder, manually download profiles, searched the web for similar issues and tried proposed solutions, even restarted my Mac and reintegrated CocoaPods although I think this is completely unrelated.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by giving the test target its own entitlements file that does not have any CloudKit references. Also for the test target I used `NSPersistentContainer` instead of `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. In other words: the application target is using CloudKit but the test target is not. This allowed the tests to succeed again while the application itself is enabled to synchronise via iCloud.